# Should I redirect user to sign in page after sign up or to the home page?

Tags: html, reactjs, forms

I know opinion based questions are not treated well on stack overflow but I had no other place.
As the title suggests,should I redirect the user to the sign In page after signup or to the home page after signup?

Comment: I would say, to home page. But probably best is to pick up few websites that are similar to yours and do what they do.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

It would highly depend on what your website is about and what is the user flow journey. Also, why do users have to register at your website.

Is your website a SaaS? If yes, high chance your user would want to go to the dashbaord.

Is your website is a news site? If yes, high chance your user would want to go to the homepage to read the news.

The location your app should redirect to is dependent on why the user would be required to sign in, and what the user is expected to be doing next.

Comment: I am making a office cafeteria app where the user registers on the website and is allowed to order food from the menu.So should I be redirecting him to the menu page?

Comment: Yes, unless there is a dashboard for whatever reasons, the menu page would be to most intuitive for users, as it is safe to assume most users who go to the app only to order the food.